# vba power point changing image border color on click

Tags: image, vba, colors, border, powerpoint

I'm trying to make an educational interactive presentation for kinder children using Power Point, and I'm trying to do a kind of test/activity in which the children have to click on some pictures according to the question. Some will be right, some don't. (for instance: can you point the tools used by a fireman? and show 4 images of different tools)
Using the mousemove event, I can reproduce a sound that says the name of the object, and using the click event I can reproduce another sound to tell the children "wrong" or "right".
Now, I would like to change the border of the picture they are clicking on (color and or width), but I have no clue how to do it in VBA. 
It must be very easy, but I don't know the sintax :-(
Any help? Please?
Thank you!

Comment: `It must be very easy, but I don't know the sintax`... I suggest doing some googling to try to find some help with the syntax. You will get best results from SO if you **show the effort** you've tried and ask where you need help, rather than getting someone to do it for you.

Comment: `Using the mousemove event`- you mean you did it in VBA or as an action setting in pp application??

Comment: Hi,I used the action setting (sorry, didn't mean to confuse anybody)

Comment: Scott Holtzman: I did a LOT of googling before asking, but the truth is that I don't know VBA. In fact, I'm not a programmer. I found this code who worked in edition mode, and tried to make some changes, but couldn't make it work in show mode: 
Sub img_border() 
With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange 
.Fill.Transparency = 0# 
.Line.Weight = 5.75 
.Line.Style = msoLineThinThick 
.Line.Visible = msoTrue 
.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(150, 150, 150) 
.Line.BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255) 
End With 
End Sub

I tried many things before asking, reading different forums and sites

Sorry I bothered you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be surprised but it's not so easy as you expected, of course, when doing smartly with classes and events.

I'll give you simple idea, so if you have time and really need it you could go this way. But there would be some problems- you will have to figure out how could you get starting borders of your shapes.

Here is idea how to start.

1. name each of the shape on the slide- select one and run the following instruction in Immediate window in VBA editor, eg.:

   ```
   ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "Fireman"
   ```
2. to change the color and line write macro for each shape (this will run only in slideshow view):

   ```
   Sub FiremanClick()

   With SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.Shapes("Fireman").Line
       .Weight = 2
       .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
   End With


   End Sub
   ```
3. in application right-click fireman shape and associate action with macro you wrote.
4. you will need to figure out how to set back standard setting of each shape and when.

Comment: KazJaw: Thank you very much. I will try to make it work. I'll let you know if I could make it! Thank you! I'm getting your point about setting back standard sttings.

Comment: KazJaw: GREAT! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I spent a couple of days trying different codes that I found on the internet, and reading many forums and sites, but your code worked perfectly for what I was looking for! As you said, It is not so easy as I expected.

Comment: You're welcome... If solved you could possibly mark the question as solved to inform others :)

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, some kind of bug happens when setting the border shape color first and then the weight, the shape border color becomes the generic blue one in PowerPoint 2010.